# How to replace a substring, but only if it occurs exactly between two words

Tags: python, regex, substring

In python, I need to  replace `" - "` with `"-"` , but only if `[SPACE][DASH][SPACE]` occurs between two words.

`[SPACE][SPACE][DASH][SPACE][SPACE]` would not be changed. I.e.:

`" - The quick - brown fox jumps  -  over the -"`  would have to change to

`" - The quick-brown fox jumps  -  over the -"`

`This is jumps[SPACE][SPACE][DASH][SPACE][SPACE] ...`

I can't wrap my head around regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex for searching with word boundary:

```
\b - \b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0q1LkI/1)

Due to word boundary on both side, it will only match when space is surrounded by word characters on both sides.

**Code:**

```
import re

test_str = " - The quick - brown fox jumps  -  over the -"


# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(r"\b - \b", '-', test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With @anubhavva's help, I built this universal function:

```
def replace_in_word(replace_in, replace_what, replace_with):
    #in string replace_in, replace_what with replace_with, and return the string
    #but only inside a word
    #if not found, return unchanged string
    return(re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % replace_what, replace_with, replace_in))
```